# react doesn't render the components on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the dev mode, everything worked as expected, but when I build the project the components didn't mount

this is my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

this is app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalStateInitialSetters />

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <Main />
              <Footer />
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```